# Swift HTTP Post: Why are these params not being recognized?

Tags: swift, nsurl

I am making a simple HTTP Post call to a webserver in Swift, and trying to pass several parameters via a Dictionary, but the server doesn't seem to receive them, what am I missing here?  I can do this in PHP, Perl, etc, but haven't quite figured out passing POST params in Swift.  Thanks.

```
var ret: NSData
var responseStr: NSString

var urlString = server + page
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!     // Creating URL
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)   // Creating Http Request
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// these params don't seem to be recognized
let params = [
    "projectid": "1234", "userid": "somename", "password": "pw"
] as Dictionary<String, String>

var err: NSError?
let requestBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
request.HTTPBody = requestBody

var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?> = nil
var error: NSErrorPointer? = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Content-Type` header with value `application/json` is usually needed for server-side apps to recognize JSON-formatted request body. So add this before you make the request:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
```

Another solution is use a library like [Just](http://justhttp.net). Your request would be:

```
Just.post(urlString, json: ["projectid": "1234", "userid": "somename", "password": "pw"])
```